# Behaviors.behaviorsLookup typical value

Tags: marionette

Quoted from [Marionette.Behavior documentation](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.3.0/marionette.behavior.html#using)

> Finally, the user must define a location for where their behaviors are stored.
>   A simple example of this would look like this:

```
  Marionette.Behaviors.behaviorsLookup = function() {
      return window.Behaviors;
  }
```

But `window.Behaviors` is undefined.  When I use `window` everything is good.  Do I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's undefined because you probably haven't defined it yet. You would create an object `window.Behaviors = {}` that would be attached to the window when the app starts. From there you could register behaviors off of that and reference `window.Behaviors` like so,

```
window.Behaviors.ExampleBehavior = Marionette.Behavior.extend({
    defaults: {},
    events: {},
    //etc..
});
```

Then inside of your `behaviorsLookup`, returning `window.Behaviors` won't be undefined. Here's the [documentation](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.3.0/marionette.behaviors.html#behaviorslookup) explaining it further